# not convert in Ltrim and Rtrim

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Customer_Fname varchar(20) not null 
    check (len(Rtrim(Ltrim(Customer_Fname))) > 1)
```

I try this syntax to check the data length, but not convert Ltrim and Rtrim.

Example:

```
insert into dbo.person(Customer_Fname) 
values ('  Mukund')
```

Answer is same as I insert value

Comment: Can you specify which database are you using,`mysql` or `sql server`?

Comment: sql server managment studio

Comment: The `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` are only used in the `CHECK` constraint - they're used to check if a given condition (`> 1`) is true - but they are **NOT** applied to the data as it's being inserted - for that, you'd need to look into an `AFTER INSERT` trigger

Comment: There is little point in the `RTRIM` too, as trailing spaces are ignored for length and comparison. `'dba'`, `'dba '` and `'dba           '` all have a `LEN` of `3`. *Leading* spaces on the other hand are included in comparisons and length calculations.

Comment: @ThomA, maybe he does a Fname+ ' ' + LastName, where non-trimmed spaces mess up the formatting

Answer (score 1):

The current trigger only checks the length after trimming. Here's an example of a trigger set to fire on INSERT and UPDATE events that strips leading or trailing spaces and checks you don't store an empty string:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_RemoveSpaces_Customer_Fname 
ON YourTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE YourTable
    SET Customer_Fname = CASE
        WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(Customer_Fname)) = '' THEN NULL
        ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(Customer_Fname))
    END
    FROM YourTable
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON YourTable.ID = i.ID
END
```

nb: you could use [TRIM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) if using SQL Server 2017 or later

Comment: Just a thought ... nullif(trim(Customer_Fname)),'')